# How to detect when the keyboard is open in mobile device? using flutter web

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, keyboard, flutter-dependencies

Flutter Web Keyboard detect

I am developing an application in flutter web that is responsive, I have been looking for several options to be able to detect when the keyboard is open when touching a text field, I have used some libraries such as flutter_keyboard_visibility, but I have not been successful for flutter web. I would like to know if you know of any option that can be implemented to detect if the keyboard is open in flutter web. Note: also use the following: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0 But it also does not return me when it is open or hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FocusNode`

```
final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
```

and assign it to your `TextField` Widget:

```
TextField(focusNode: _focusNode,)
```

create a method where you want to add your logic when keyboard is active or not:

```
void isActive(){
    if(_focusNode.hasFocus){
      debugPrint("Keyboard is active");
    }else{
      debugPrint("Keyboard is not active");
    }
  }
```

now in `initState` method add a listener to `_focusNode` and pass the above method:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _focusNode.addListener(isActive);
    super.initState();
  }
```

also, make sure to `dispose` the _focusNode.

Full Code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  void isActive(){
    if(_focusNode.hasFocus){
      debugPrint("Keyboard is active");
    }else{
      debugPrint("Keyboard is not active");
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusNode.addListener(isActive);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(focusNode: _focusNode,),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```